# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.ConnectionString.getRetryWritesValue()Ljava/lang/Boolean

Tags: java, mongodb

I was trying to move to mongodb new drivers from **3.8** to **3.9**.

After the change, I then get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.ConnectionString.getRetryWritesValue()Ljava/lang/Boolean
```

Here is my connection string:

```
String connectionString = "mongodb://admin:admin@localhost:27017/?authSource=test&connectTimeoutMS=30000"
```

And here is the line throwing exception:

```
new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(connectionString));
```

Comment: You might be missing the Mongo Java Driver .jar from your classpath.  Q: Do you have it?  Q: Are you using Maven or Gradle?  Here are the [3.8 API](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/javadoc/com/mongodb/ConnectionString.html) and [3.9 API](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/javadoc/com/mongodb/ConnectionString.html) docs.

Comment: i am using maven